# How to find the new coordinates and bearing of a circle in C#?

Tags: c#, geometry, trigonometry

I am not very familiar with trigonometry, but I have a circle with two tangents connecting each other in a 90-degree angle. One of the tangents is on the right side of the circle, the other at the bottom (see below).
[image: Example 1]
If the angle between the tangents increases, for example from 90 to 127 degrees, how can I calculate the new position of the circle in C#? In the example below, the circle shifted to the right so that the tangent on the right side of the circle remains, well, a tangent. What I need is a small piece of C# code to show me how to get the coordinates and bearing to reposition the circle so that it will look like in the image below.
[image: Example 2]

**Note: AB is not always horizontal and the coordinates are not cartesian but EPSG:4326.**

Comment: Is line AB always horizontal, and guaranteed to remain so?

Comment: No. Line AB will not be always horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method below returns the coordinates of the center of a circle so that it can be placed within two lines that intersect each other. The lines become the circle's tangents (see images below).

I use this method to position circles within lines with angles >= 90 degrees. The method relies on NetTopologySuite and a couple of my own functions. I hope the code is self-explanatory, but if you have questions, just let me know.

```
public static Coordinate CircleCenter(Coordinate tip1, Coordinate tail, Coordinate tip2, double radius_km)
    {
        double bearing1, bearing2;
        if (Orientation.IsCCW(new Coordinate[] { tip1, tail, tip2, tip1 }))
        {
            bearing1 = Functions.CalculateBearing(tail.ToGeoCoordinate(), tip1.ToGeoCoordinate());
            bearing2 = Functions.CalculateBearing(tail.ToGeoCoordinate(), tip2.ToGeoCoordinate());
        }
        else
        {
            bearing2 = Functions.CalculateBearing(tail.ToGeoCoordinate(), tip1.ToGeoCoordinate());
            bearing1 = Functions.CalculateBearing(tail.ToGeoCoordinate(), tip2.ToGeoCoordinate());
        }
        double bearingDifference = Functions.BearingDifference(bearing1, bearing2);
        double bisector = (bearing1 + bearingDifference / 2) % 360;
        double distance = radius_km / Math.Sin(bearingDifference.ToRadians() / 2);
        return Functions.TargetCoordinate(tail.ToGeoCoordinate(), bisector, distance).ToCoordinate();
    }
```

Here are a couple of screenshots of a working demo with the method above.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Circle center coordinates are

```
cx = B.x - R / tan(Theta/2) 
cy = B.y + R
```

because center lies at the bisector of angle `Theta` (ABC)

Comment: Line AB is not guaranteed to be horizontal.

Comment: @Peter Author have not specified this, really problem was not stated properly, so I answered using information available from the picture.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my oversight. I edited the text to make the requirements clearer.

Comment: @MBo I appreciate your answer since it pointed me in the right direction when you mentioned the bisector.

Comment: I will give it a try. I managed to get the correct bearing from the line's intersection, thanks to your suggestion. With that, I will be able to position the circle correctly if I can find a way to calculate the distance (length) between the line's intersection coordinates and the radius coordinates at the point where the circle touches both lines.

Comment: You don't need that all if radius is known

Comment: It is worth to define problem parameters, to avoid telepathy usage ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two conceptual solutions:

**Solution 1:**

1. Use transforms to rotate A and C around B so that AB is horizontal.

   - Translate the points so that B is at the origin.
   - Calculate the angle AB
   - Rotate A and C around B using the angle calculated in (b)
2. Use the solution suggested by MBo on the transformed A B C
3. Use the inverse of the transforms in step 1 on the centrepoint that was calculated in step 2. The result is the centrepoint of the circle.

**Solution 2:**

1. Find parallel lines to AB and BC, r away from them.

   - Find the slope of the line.
   - Find lines perpendicular to each (at any point)
   - Find the point on the perpendicular line r away from the point where it intersects with the AB or BC. This is a point on the parallel line.
2. Find the intersection of the two parallel lines. This is the centrepoint of the circle.

With either approach, it might be a good idea to look at matrix transforms, as these provide an elegant way to deal with compound transforms, and it is easy to compute their inverse.